# Non-recursive Knights Tour implementation in C using Warnsdoff's rule

Tags: beginner, algorithm, c, chess

Just trying to get used to writing programs in C so have written this program to find valid Knights Tours on a 8x8 board. I guess my queries are more focused on my use of the language and how I could or should do things better.

A little about the code. It is a C implementation based on something I wrote previously in python. It uses Warnsdoff's heuristic to try to find a knights tour on a 8x8 board. This rule follows that you should choose the square with the least available of successor squares as your next move. This is implemented by a non recursive function that loops until it can find no more successor nodes or the tour has reached the length of completion. Finding the successor nodes is achieved by the `NodeSuccessor` function which loops through possible moves defined in the array `Deltas` which is filtered by the already visited squares and the dimensions of the board. The `SelectedNode` function then pics optimal solution by counting the number of successors for each node then in case of a draw taking into account the distance from the center. Draws after this are dismissed as equally good and the first one to be assigned. In this case I have not incorporated backtracking and though I haven't tested it rigorously previous a previous implementation of similar design found a valid tour from any start position 99% of the time for any MxN board >= 6 where M and N are both even.

But maybe to focus more on my use of the language C. Being used to more high level languages what could I be doing better here. Are my choice of data structures ok? Should I be doing anything different in the case of handling memory? - Here I have just set a fixed size for the `VECTOR.nodes` and `PATH.Path` lengths as i concluded that I don't want a path bigger than 64 and the available successor nodes can only go up to 8. I haven't utilised pointers at all, is there any need to in this case? I'm just trying to get a feel for the best practices.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct { int x; int y; } VECTOR;

typedef struct { VECTOR nodes[8]; int length; } NODE_LIST;

typedef struct {
    VECTOR path[64];
    int pathLength;
    int success;
} PATH;

const VECTOR Deltas[8] = {{-2, 1}, {-2,-1}, {-1,-2}, { 1,-2},  /* possible moves a knight  */
                          { 2,-1}, { 2, 1}, { 1, 2}, {-1, 2}}; /* can make in vector space.*/

PATH KnightsTour(VECTOR start);

VECTOR SelectedNode(NODE_LIST nodelist, PATH tour);

NODE_LIST NodeSuccessors(VECTOR node, PATH path);

int NodeNotInPath(VECTOR node, PATH path);

float EuclideanDistance(VECTOR node);

int main()
{
    VECTOR start = {3,3};
    PATH tour = KnightsTour(start);
    if (tour.success)
    {
        printf("Success!\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < tour.pathLength; i++)
        {
            printf("[%d, %d], ", tour.path[i].x,  tour.path[i].y);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed! \n");
    }
    printf("\n%d \n", tour.pathLength);
}

PATH KnightsTour(VECTOR start)
{
    /* takes start co-ordinates and try's to find a valid
     tour else fails */
    VECTOR node = start;
    PATH tour;
    tour.pathLength = 0;
    tour.success = 0;
    while (!tour.success)
    {
        tour.path[tour.pathLength] = node;
        tour.pathLength++;
        if (tour.pathLength >= 64)
        {
            tour.success = 1; /* found a tour; set exit condition */
            continue;
        }
        NODE_LIST successors = NodeSuccessors(node, tour);
        if (successors.length != 0)
            node = SelectedNode(successors, tour);
        else
            break; /* failed to find a tour no valid successors */
    }
    return tour;
}

VECTOR SelectedNode(NODE_LIST nodelist, PATH tour)
{
    /* Following Warnsdoff's rule this function searches for the 
     node that has the least number of successor nodes then incase of a
     draw tries to tiebreak on distance from the center of the board
     if this tiebreaks also the first added is selected. 
     */
    int bestNode = 8; // max amount of possible successor nodes.
    float currentFurthest = 0;
    VECTOR selectedNode = {-1, -1}; // init incase of fail.
    for (int n = 0; n < nodelist.length; n++)
    {
        int len = NodeSuccessors(nodelist.nodes[n], tour).length;
        if (len <= bestNode)
        {
            if (len == bestNode){
                int eucDist = EuclideanDistance(nodelist.nodes[n]);
                if (eucDist > currentFurthest)
                { 
                    bestNode = len;
                    currentFurthest = eucDist;
                    selectedNode = nodelist.nodes[n];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                bestNode = len;
                selectedNode = nodelist.nodes[n];
            }
        }
    }
    return selectedNode;
}

NODE_LIST NodeSuccessors(VECTOR node, PATH path)
{
    /* Returns available move nodes from the current position. */
    NODE_LIST successors;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        VECTOR N = {node.x + Deltas[i].x, node.y + Deltas[i].y};
        if ((N.x <  8) && (N.y <  8) &&
            (N.x >= 0) && (N.y >= 0) && NodeNotInPath(N, path))
        {
            successors.nodes[count] = N;
            count++;
        }
    }
    successors.length = count;
    return successors;
}

int NodeNotInPath(VECTOR node, PATH path)
{
    /* Searches for a node a given path and returns 0 if found else 1 */
    for (int i = 0; i < path.pathLength; i++)
    {
        if ((path.path[i].x == node.x) && (path.path[i].y == node.y))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

float EuclideanDistance(VECTOR node) 
{
    /* returns approx Euclidean distance^2 from the center of the board
     basically the hypotenuse of a triangle */
    float center = 7.0 / 2;
    return (pow((node.x - center), 2) + pow((node.y - center), 2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. RATHER THAN SHOUT YOUR TYPES NAMES LIKE `VECTOR`, consider `vector` or `Vector`.
2. Odd to exit the loop with `continue` and `break` in `KnightsTour()`.  Suggest `break;` with `{}` for both.
3. Simplify `EuclideanDistance()` and use `int` math.

   ```
   int center = 7;
   int dx2 = node.x*2 - center;
   int dy2 = node.y*2 - center;
   return dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2;
   ```
4. With functions that return 1 or 0, consider `bool` instead

   ```
   // int NodeNotInPath(VECTOR node, PATH path)
   bool NodeNotInPath(VECTOR node, PATH path) {
     ...
     // return 1;
     return true;
   ```
5. Avoid `Not` in 1/0, true/false function names.  Reversion the return value

   ```
   // bool NodeNotInPath(VECTOR node, PATH path);
   bool NodeInPath(VECTOR node, PATH path) {
     ...
     return false;
   ```
6. Minor: `VECTOR` is passed around a lot by value.  Typically structures are  passed by their address.  Yet `VECTOR` is small.  Consider making it smaller

   ```
   // typedef struct { int x; int y; } VECTOR;
   typedef struct { short x; short y; } VECTOR;
   // or 
   typedef struct { signed char x; signed char y; } VECTOR;
   ```
7. `PATH` is passed around by value.  This larger structure should have its address passed.   With `PATH KnightsTour(VECTOR start)`, suggest passing in the address of the `PATH` and return success `bool`.

   ```
   // int NodeNotInPath(VECTOR node, PATH path)
   int NodeNotInPath(VECTOR node, const PATH *path)
     ...  
     // if ((path.path[i].x
     if ((path->path[i].x

    // PATH KnightsTour(VECTOR start)
    bool KnightsTour(VECTOR start, PATH *tour)
      // tour.pathLength = 0;
      // tour.success = 0;
      tour->pathLength = 0;
      tour->success = 0;
   ```
8. Avoid magic numbers. Instead:

   ```
   #define BOARD_N 8
   #define BOARD_NN (BOARD_N * BOARD_N)
   #define DELTA_N 8

   typedef struct {
     VECTOR nodes[DELTA_N]

   typedef struct {
     VECTOR path[BOARD_NN];

   if (tour.pathLength >= BOARD_NN)
   ```
9. An arithmetic compare looks more self documenting for variables thar have values like 0,1,2,3,4...

   ```
   // if (successors.length != 0)
   if (successors.length > 0)
   ```